# How to display products under Category in sql in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping, rollup

I have the following table:

[image: product]

where the products are in different categories and i am excepting the output:

[image: output]

like product and its cost need to be displayed under category(For category cost value i want to display total products cost) .I tried with different approaches by using roll up and grouping , but i am not getting excepted output.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and where you fail. It genereally helps, if your read the [FAQ] and [ask] first. If it is possible, create a http://sqlfiddle.com/ for us, so we can give you some hands on results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it goes:

Sample Data:

```
CREATE TABLE #product (ID INT, Category VARCHAR(50), Product VARCHAR(50), Value INT)
INSERT INTO #product
VALUES(1,'Non-veg','Chicken',150),
(2,'Non-veg','Mutton',200),
(3,'Non-veg','Fish',220),
(4,'Non-veg','Prawns',250),
(5,'Veg','Gobi',100),
(6,'Veg','Parota',45),
(7,'Veg','vegbirani',150)
```

Query using [GROUP BY with ROLLUP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305(v=sql.90).aspx)

```
SELECT  Category, Product,
       SUM(Value) AS Value
FROM #product
GROUP BY Category, Product WITH ROLLUP
```

Results:

[image]

you can further manipulate the results:

```
SELECT  COALESCE(product,category,'Total') Category,
       SUM(Value) AS Value
FROM #product
GROUP BY Category, Product WITH ROLLUP
```

Result:

[image]

To answer the comment below: "is there any way to display Category first then Products" this seemed to work:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT  Category, Product,
       SUM(Value) AS Value,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY Product  ) AS rn
FROM #product
GROUP BY Category, Product WITH ROLLUP)

SELECT  Category = COALESCE(A.product,A.category,'Total') , A.Value 
FROM CTE AS A 
ORDER BY ISNULL(A.category,'zzzzzz') ,rn
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: I (personally) believe that the inclusion of sample data - as you have done here - or at least an [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) should be made mandatory for such questions and should be provided by the one asking the question. But great that you did so in your answer.

Comment: @Ralph totally agree with you there

Comment: You could add a `CASE WHEN category is null or product is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 as BOLD_INDICATOR` to let the display know when to use bold.

Comment: Thanks @kamran ,is there any way to display Category first then Products

Comment: @chandra I just added the solution to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much @KamranFarzami

Comment: @chandra you're welcome. if my answer answered your question feel free to selected as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using Rollup you would do it like this.

```
SELECT  COALESCE(product,category,'Total') Category,
        SUM(VALUE) cost
FROM    products
GROUP BY ROLLUP(category,product)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this... doesn't give your exact output but it's close...

```
Select category, product, sum(value) as value
From TableName
group by grouping sets ((category),(category, product))
```